# Android Kotlin Dagger 2 component not generated

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have no Idea why my DaggerComponent is not generated after rebuild the project.

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class NewsScope
```

---

```
@NewsScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [BaseComponent::class],
    modules = [NewsModule::class]
)
interface NewsComponent {
    fun newsManager(): NewsManager
}
```

---

```
@NewsScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [BaseComponent::class],
    modules = [NewsModule::class]
)
interface NewsComponent {
    fun newsManager(): NewsManager
}
```

---

```
@Module
class NewsModule {

    @NewsScope
    @Provides
    fun provideMoshiConverterFactory(): MoshiConverterFactory {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        return MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi)
    }

    @NewsScope
    @Provides
    fun provideNewsApi(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): NewsApi {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(NewsApi.API_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
                .createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .build()

        val retrofitApi = retrofit.create(RetrofitNewsApi::class.java)

        return RetrofitNewsApiImpl(retrofitApi)
    }

    @NewsScope
    @Provides
    fun provideNewsManager(newsApi: NewsApi): NewsManager {
        return NewsManager(newsApi)
    }
}
```

---

```
class NewsFragment : BaseFragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var newsManager: NewsManager private set


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        newsManager = DaggerNewsComponent.builder() 
            .baseComponent(baseComponent())
            .newsModule(NewsModule())
            .build().newsManager()
    }
}
```

- *** DaggerNewsComponent not Generated
- $dagger_version = "2.23.2"
- AndroidX was implemented
- I am a iOS Pro but Android Noob

  implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
  implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
  implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"

  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android- processor:$dagger_version"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `kapt` next to `annotationProcessor`

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.2'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2'
```

and add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at top of your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Yes and also add

```
android {
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}
```